# ER-Model for Borrowing-Lending-Network?

Tags: database, entity, conceptual

I plan on creating my first database so this is going to be a newbie question. My database is supposed to be for a Borrowing-Lending-Network where users can borrow products from other users. Creating one user account should be sufficient for being able to borrow and lend and the same time. The only exception should be that a user cannot borrow products that were offered by himself.

So my question is which of these two options is the better one:

Having one entity for user which can borrow and lend. Entity name "USER".
Having two different entities for both borrowers and givers in order to prevent a user from borrowing his own products?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I would recommend a 3rd approach:

- `USER` model = these are the users who can either borrow or lend
- `ITEM` model = this identifies the items that can be borrowed and who owns them

  - `owner_id` = references the ID of the `USER` object.
- `HISTORY` model = this tracks the lending history and could include things like:

  - `item_id` = references the id of the `ITEM`
  - `borrower_id` = references the id of the `USER` who borrowed the item
  - `borrowed_at` = timestamp of when the item was borrowed
  - `returned_at` = timestamp of when the time was returned to owner.

With this model it would be straight-forward to ensure that that the borrower_id and the item.owner_id are not the same and to ensure that the same item can not be lent out to two different borrowers at the same time.

From a SQL perspective, you could find all items that I do not own by doing something like (where MY_ID is my user.id):

```
SELECT * from items where owner_id != MY_ID;
```

If you want to find all of the items that are NOT owned by me and are NOT currently borrowed, perhaps:

```
SELECT * from items where owner_id != MY_ID and id not in (select item_id from history where borrowed_at is not null and returned_at is null);
```

The syntax would be different for other languages of course.

A half-dozen different ways you could model this, but without knowing more about your use-case, this is where I would start.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! What I don't get though is: How does that ensure that the borrower_id and the item.owner_id are not the same?

Comment: @lioli - I updated my answer to address your question.